Не могу разобраться, как отправлять запросы магнит requests python
С помощью Burp узнал какой запрос отправляется в моб приложении Магнита при добавлении товара в корзину.
Отправил тот же запрос у себя и он успешно добавился, однако, если подставить другой артикул товара, то выдает 403 ошибку, доступ запрещен.
Заметил, что при каждом новом запросе в headers меняется: 'X-Request-Sign', остальные заголовки остаются неизменными, удалил их в вопросе.
Не понимаю, как передавать этот заголовок в новый запрос, чтобы он отдал 200 статус, или это невозможно?
import requests

headers = {
    'X-Request-Sign': 'e831e827c9026b44bc1fff5d0026296fa76603be7b65c799b1571d519a1ee0c0cd70b558acb1be5dff99f836e76080b97ad2aa2bfe84696d3e66bc899cb96dc4',
}

json_data = {
    'items': [
        {
            'goodId': '1000055826',
            'utm': {},
            'qnty': 1,
            'offerId': '1000055826',
        },
    ],
}

response = requests.put('https://middle-api.magnit.ru/v1/carts/lite', headers=headers, json=json_data, verify=False)


X-Request-Sign - это подпись запроса, которая зависит от timestamp и/или от самого тела запроса, поэтому для каждого запроса она разная, но один такой хедер может жить какое-то время (для уникального тела) - поэтому вы получили респонз с 200, отправив еще раз запрос.
Один из способов понять как формируется X-Request-Sign - попытаться разреверсить приложение и найти генерацию.
